# R language unable to insert in postgresql using postgresqlWriteTable

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I am new to R and trying to insert R dataframe in Postgresql. Everytime whenever i try to execute my rscripts.R, I am getting the following error:

"In postgresqlWriteTable(conn, name, value, ...) :  table customervalidation exists in database: aborting assignTable"

Table customervalidation already exists in postgresql, I am trying to insert the content of SampleData.csv in this table. All the headers of the csv are already present in the table and they are all in lowercase.

Command line argument

```
./script.R batch SampleData.csv yes no
```

rscripts.R content

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

options(echo=TRUE) # if you want see commands in output file
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
print(args)
# trailingOnly=TRUE means that only your arguments are returned, check:
# print(commandsArgs(trailingOnly=FALSE))

batchIndicator <- tolower(args[1])
filename <- args[2]
isHeaderPresent <-args[3]
isRunTheBatch<-args[4]
rm(args)
#Library files
library(RPostgreSQL)
#now check whether it is immediate or batch.
# if it is immediate then real time prediction needs to prepare.
# if it is batch then whole batch set needs to prepare and keep the results in a separate file.
if(isHeaderPresent == "yes")
{
  header = TRUE
}else
{
  if(isHeaderPresent == "no"){

    header = FALSE
  }
}

  print(paste("Processing for Batch mode for filename ", filename))
  # Start body for other function
  data <-read.csv(filename,header = header, sep=",")
  drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
  con <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), dbname = "customervalidation", host = "localhost", port =5432 , user = "user", password = "pwd")
  dbWriteTable(con,"customervalidation",data,row.names=FALSE)
  #end body for other function
```

And content of SampleData.csv
[image: CSV content here]

Please help me in identifying the error what is missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid error write like this

```
     dbWriteTable(con,"customervalidation",data,row.names=FALSE,append = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is rather self-explanatory: The table already exists. If you look at the [manual](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/DBI/html/dbReadTable.html) you'll see there are two options:

- overwrite    a logical specifying whether to overwrite an existing table
  or not. Its default is FALSE.
- append   a logical specifying whether to
  append to an existing table in the DBMS. Its default is FALSE.

You have to specify one of them as TRUE.